# Python Setuptools / pyproject.toml - Console Scripts Can't Import Main Package Name: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, importerror, pyproject.toml

### Issue

I'm making a python template which is supposed to be able to be run in 3 different ways:

1. Run `python python3-template.py` in the main directory (just imports the directory-based package `python3_template` and runs `python3_template.run()`)
2. Build a pyinstaller `.exe` from `python3-template.py` and run that
3. Build a wheel with the console script `python3-template = "python3_template:run"` and run that

I have `1` and `2` working perfectly, and the wheel for `3` builds with all of the data included. However, after installing the wheel, and trying to run `python3-template`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Ella\miniconda3\envs\build\Scripts\python3-template.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python3_template'
```

Additionally, I can't `import python3_template` in the interactive interpreter, with the same error. I can import the package when I am in the main project directory just fine (of course, it's loading from the `python3_project` directory), but I can't get it to import as a regular installed package.

### Project Info

Here is the directory structure:

```
python3-template/
├── docs/
│   └── example.jpg
├── python3_template/
│   ├── constants/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── defaults.py
│   │   ├── enums.py
│   │   ├── links.py
│   │   ├── paths.py
│   │   ├── platform.py
│   │   ├── resources.py
│   │   └── version.py
│   ├── helpers/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── core.py
│   ├── resources/
│   │   ├── icon.ico
│   │   └── icon.png
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── calculator.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── version.yml
├── build.bat
├── environment.yml
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pyproject.toml
├── python3-template.py
├── README.md
└── README_pypi.md
```

And here is the `pyproject.toml`:

```js
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "python3-template"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A Python 3 Template"
readme = "README_pypi.md"
license= {file = "LICENSE"}
authors = [
    {name = "Ella Jameson", email = "ellagjameson@gmail.com"}
]

classifiers = []
dependencies = [
    "pyyaml"
]

[project.urls]
homepage = "https://github.com/nimaid/python3-template"
repository = "https://github.com/nimaid/python3-template"
issues = "https://github.com/nimaid/python3-template/issues"


[project.scripts]
python3-template = "python3_template:run"

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["python3_template"]
```

I've even made a branch of my repository that you can play with if you need to: [https://github.com/nimaid/python3-template/tree/init-but-can't-run-script-import-error](https://github.com/nimaid/python3-template/tree/init-but-can%27t-run-script-import-error)

### What I've Tried So Far

- Renaming the project to have no hyphens or underscore (no effect)
- Using different script endpoints like `python3_template.main:run` (no effect)
- Changing the package name to use underscores instead of dashes (`setuptools` overrides this back to a dash)

### Summary

I have no clue why this isn't working with this template. I've released packages in the past with what I'm pretty sure is the same structure, but I may have made an error in transferring those patterns into this template. I have no other ideas as to why it won't work, and I would very much appreciate any help you can give! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Setuptools wasn't automatically discovering the package because my directory wasn't exactly a standard format. From [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#setuptools-specific-configuration):

```
When both py-modules and packages are left unspecified, setuptools will attempt to perform Automatic discovery, which should cover most popular project directory organization techniques, such as the src-layout and the flat-layout.
```

I re-structured my project to match the stadard [`src-layout`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout), and changed my `pyproject.toml` to this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "python3-template"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A Python 3 Template"
readme = "README_pypi.md"
license= {file = "LICENSE"}
authors = [
    {name = "Ella Jameson", email = "ellagjameson@gmail.com"}
]

classifiers = []
dependencies = [
    "pyyaml"
]

[project.urls]
homepage = "https://github.com/nimaid/python3-template"
repository = "https://github.com/nimaid/python3-template"
issues = "https://github.com/nimaid/python3-template/issues"


[project.scripts]
python3-template = "python3_template:run"

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

After updating my `MANIFEST.in`, `build.bat`, and a few other files that referenced the project directory, I can run my project in all 3 desired forms!

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!